# Server Memory with Magento

Tags: ubuntu, memory-usage, configuration

I have a cloud server with the following specifications:

- 2vCPUs
- 4G RAM
- 160GB Disk Space
- Network 400Mb/s
- System Image: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I am only running Magento CE 1.7.0.2 on this server. Nothing else.

Usually, the server has a loading time of 4-5 seconds. Recently, this has dropped to over 30 seconds and sometimes the server just goes away and I get HTTP error reports to my email stating that HTTP requests took more than 20000ms.

Running top command and sorting them returns the following:

`top - 15:29:07 up  3:40,  1 user,  load average: 28.59, 25.95, 22.91
Tasks: 112 total,  30 running,  82 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 90.2%us,  9.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.2%st
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
31901 www-data  20   0  360m  71m 5840 R    7  1.8   1:39.51 apache2
32084 www-data  20   0  362m  72m 5548 R    7  1.8   1:31.56 apache2
32089 www-data  20   0  348m  59m 5660 R    7  1.5   1:41.74 apache2
32295 www-data  20   0  343m  54m 5532 R    7  1.4   2:00.78 apache2
32303 www-data  20   0  354m  65m 5260 R    7  1.6   1:38.76 apache2
32304 www-data  20   0  346m  56m 5544 R    7  1.4   1:41.26 apache2
32305 www-data  20   0  348m  59m 5640 R    7  1.5   1:50.11 apache2
32291 www-data  20   0  358m  69m 5256 R    6  1.7   1:44.26 apache2
32517 www-data  20   0  345m  56m 5532 R    6  1.4   1:45.56 apache2
30473 www-data  20   0  355m  66m 5680 R    6  1.7   2:00.05 apache2
32093 www-data  20   0  352m  63m 5848 R    6  1.6   1:53.23 apache2
32302 www-data  20   0  345m  56m 5512 R    6  1.4   1:55.87 apache2
32433 www-data  20   0  346m  57m 5500 S    6  1.4   1:31.58 apache2
32638 www-data  20   0  354m  65m 5508 R    6  1.6   1:36.59 apache2
32230 www-data  20   0  347m  57m 5524 R    6  1.4   1:33.96 apache2
32231 www-data  20   0  355m  66m 5512 R    6  1.7   1:37.47 apache2
32233 www-data  20   0  354m  64m 6032 R    6  1.6   1:59.74 apache2
32300 www-data  20   0  355m  66m 5672 R    6  1.7   1:43.76 apache2
32510 www-data  20   0  347m  58m 5512 R    6  1.5   1:42.54 apache2
32521 www-data  20   0  348m  59m 5508 R    6  1.5   1:47.99 apache2
32639 www-data  20   0  344m  55m 5512 R    6  1.4   1:34.25 apache2
32083 www-data  20   0  345m  56m 5696 R    5  1.4   1:59.42 apache2
32085 www-data  20   0  347m  58m 5692 R    5  1.5   1:42.29 apache2
32293 www-data  20   0  353m  64m 5676 R    5  1.6   1:52.73 apache2
32301 www-data  20   0  348m  59m 5564 R    5  1.5   1:49.63 apache2
32528 www-data  20   0  351m  62m 5520 R    5  1.6   1:36.11 apache2
31523 mysql     20   0 3460m 576m 8288 S    5 14.4   2:06.91 mysqld
32002 www-data  20   0  345m  55m 5512 R    5  1.4   2:01.88 apache2
32080 www-data  20   0  357m  68m 5512 S    5  1.7   1:31.30 apache2
32163 www-data  20   0  347m  58m 5512 S    5  1.5   1:58.68 apache2
32509 www-data  20   0  345m  56m 5504 R    5  1.4   1:49.54 apache2
32306 www-data  20   0  358m  68m 5504 S    4  1.7   1:53.29 apache2
32165 www-data  20   0  344m  55m 5524 S    4  1.4   1:40.71 apache2
32640 www-data  20   0  345m  56m 5528 R    4  1.4   1:36.49 apache2
31888 www-data  20   0  359m  70m 5664 R    4  1.8   1:57.07 apache2
32511 www-data  20   0  357m  67m 5512 S    3  1.7   1:47.00 apache2
32054 www-data  20   0  357m  68m 5660 S    2  1.7   1:53.10 apache2
    1 root      20   0 24452 2276 1232 S    0  0.1   0:01.58 init`

Moreover, running free -m returns the following:

`total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4003       3919         83          0        118        901
-/+ buffers/cache:       2899       1103
Swap:            0          0          0`

To investigate this further, I have installed apache buddy, it recommeneded that I need to reduce the maxclient connections. Which I did.

I also installed MysqlTuner and it suggests that I need to set my innodb_buffer_pool_size to >= 3.0G.

However, I cannot do that, since the whole memory is 4G.

Here is the output from apache buddy:

`### GENERAL REPORT ###
Settings considered for this report:
        Your server's physical RAM:             4003MB
        Apache's MaxClients directive:          40
        Apache MPM Model:                       prefork
        Largest Apache process (by memory):     73.77MB
[ OK ]  Your MaxClients setting is within an acceptable range.
        Max potential memory usage:             2950.8 MB
        Percentage of RAM allocated to Apache   73.72 %`

And this is the output of MySQLTuner:

`-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 47m 22s (675K q [237.552 qps], 12K conn, TX: 1B, RX: 300M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 45% / 55%
[--] Total buffers: 2.1G global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.5G (64% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/675K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 26% (40/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 36.0M/18.7M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (245K cached / 105 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 92.5% (500K cached / 541K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 302886
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1 temp sorts / 15K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 12135
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 25% (8K on disk / 32K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 90% (1K created / 12K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 17% (400 open / 2K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 12% (123/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (196K immediate / 196K locks)
[!!] InnoDB  buffer pool / data size: 2.0G/3.5G
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 64M)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_cache (> 400)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 3G)`

Last but not least, the server still has more than 60% of free disk space.

Now, based on the above, I have few questions:

1. Are these numbers normal? Do they make sense?
2. Do I need to upgrade the server?
3. If I don't need to upgrade and my configuration is not correct, how do I optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating this further. I found that MySQL database was around 3.6GB of size. This needed a buffer pool size equal or more than that as recommended by MySQL Tuner. Which meant I had to upgrade my server.

However, investigating the database itself showed that around 3GB were all LOG FILES from Magento. Once I cleared all the log files (which apparently have been piling for nearly two years), the database size went way down and the server went back to normal.

Tools that helped me figure this out and even optimize my server more are:

1. Apache Buddy
2. MySQL Tuner
3. Tuning Primer

Hope someone finds this helpful!